# Can a vector reference a 2-D array in Java?

Tags: java, vector, multidimensional-array

Basically, I want to create a 2-D array that grows in size at runtime. Could I do this using a vector in Java?

Would these be right then?

int [] [] x = new x [100] [100];

Vector x= new Vector();

To add elements into the array-

```
for i=0 to 99
   for j=0 to 99
   x.addElement(x[i] [j]);
```

essentially, it would be just the same like referencing any other object, only here, I've to specify the index numbers as well, right?

I'm a novice at Java. So I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: `Vector` is more or less deprecated in Java, as compared to `ArrayList`.

Comment: Why are you reusing the name `x` for both the array and `Vector`?  You can't use the same variable name twice in the same scope; this is just adding confusion to your question.

Comment: You cannot create a 2D structure that automatically grows in both dimensions using just the collections in JDK.

Comment: @Affe ArrayList of ArrayList does it count ?

Comment: @dreamcrash It would be difficult to make sure that all of the secondary arraylists contained within the main arraylist were the same length, although it would be easily doable with a wrapper class of some kind to regulate access.

Comment: @dreamcrash you will still have to add code to manually grow the first dimension by adding additional lists to it when an un-populated index is accessed.

Comment: thanks for the replies. @Affe.. I just want it to grow in 1-D.. the second dimension lenght is fixed

Comment: @Affe I see you point. I was also basing in this previews thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232257/2d-dynamic-array-using-arraylist-in-java

Comment: @LouisWasserman: `Vector` isn't deprecated, it's just thread safe.  If one doesn't need the thread safety, then it's painless to switch it out for `ArrayList` otherwise.  99% of the time though, one would use `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Makoto: I think that's why he qualified it with "more or less".  It doesn't bear the deprecated tag, but new libraries take care not to ever rely on it (favouring the `List` interface over any particular implementation) and it has fallen out of favour with developers too.  Plus, the docs recommend not using it when thread safety is not relevant.  So it's *de facto* deprecated.  For synchronized lists there are better implementations that don't bear the baggage of Vector, and are actually threadsafe where Vector requires explicit synchronization.

Comment: Yup.  Not only is `Vector` synchronized when you usually don't need it; it's often synchronized in the _wrong way_ -- it's more useful to synchronize entire groups of operations than to synchronize each operation individually, for which `Lists.synchronizedList(ArrayList)` is more useful anyway.  Like I said -- "more or less deprecated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java has neither 2D arrays nor 2D growing vectors.

It has array of arrays or vector of vectors.

In your example, you created 1D vector of `Object`s:

```
Vector x= new Vector();
```

is similar to growing array of type `Object[] x`

So, when you do

```
y.addElement(x[i][j]);
```

Java does "boxing", i.e. it does

```
y.addElement(new Integer(x[i][j]));
```

Since you added 100x100 elements into 1D array, you will need to calculate location yourself

```
y.get(i*numcols+j)
```

So, to avoid all this, use vector of vectors like example below. The example copies newly fixed size array into vector of vectors:

```
   // creates fixed size 2D array with zeros
    int [] [] x = new int [50][50]; 

    // creates empty vector of vectors of integers
    // y is of type Vector<Vector<Integer>>
    // y.get(row) is of type Vector<Integer>>
    // y.get(row).get(col) is of type Integer
    Vector<Vector<Integer>> y = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>(); 

    // set the size of vector of vectors (number of rows)
    // each row will be null for now
    y.setSize(x.length);

    // enumerating rows
    for(int row=0; row<x.length; ++row) {

        log.info("row {}", row);

        // assign empty vector for row
        y.set(row, new Vector<Integer>());

        // set row size (number of columns)
        y.get(row).setSize(x[row].length);

        // enumerating columns of current row
        for(int col=0; col<x[row].length; ++col) {

            // setting the value for a cell
            y.get(row).set(col, x[row][col]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what to suggest to you without knowing the cases you need to optimize for.

For example, this simple wrapper around a map is a [sparse 2D matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) optimized for setting and getting specific indices (doesn't need to "grow" at all), but bad for iterating over all indices.

```
public class SparseMatrix<T> {
    private final Map<Coordinates, T> map = new HashMap<Coordinates, T>();
    private final T defaultValue;

    public SparseMatrix(T defaultValue) {
       this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    private static class Coordinates {
        private final int[] coordinates;

        Coordinates(int... coordinates) {
            this.coordinates = coordinates;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return Arrays.equals(coordinates, ((Coordinates)o).coordinates);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(coordinates);
        }
    }

    public T get(int x, int y) {
        T value = map.get(new Coordinates(x, y));
        if ( value == null ) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    public T set(int x, int y, T val) {
        return map.put(new Coordinates(x, y), val);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SparseMatrix<Integer> matrix = new SparseMatrix<Integer>(0);
matrix.set(3, 5, 7);
int seven = matrix.get(3, 5);
int zero = matrix.get(3, 6); //not set yet, uses default
```

It can also be very easily adapted to N-dimensions.  Of course in production code you wouldn't roll your own, you'd use a library that does a better job.

Comment: Well, basically, Im just accepting a bunch of user values.. a matrix if you will, and i dont know the size of the matrix.. i just want my array to be able to hold enough values and not run of size.. since its a matrix.. im opting for 2-D

Comment: @user1767157: A sparse matrix like this is probably your best bet then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList` which is equivalent to dynamic array.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aDynamicArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(2);
aDynamicArray.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
aDynamicArray.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Now you can use you `for` loop as following:

```
int [] [] x = new x [2] [100];
for i=0 to 1 
   for j=0 to 99
       aDynamicArray.get(i).add(x[i] [j]);
```

EDIT:

> if i wanted to access x[2] [3] , how would i do that in the arraylist?

`x[2][3]` means value at 3rd row and 4th column. So, Fisrt line of code will change as follows: (to accomodate 3 rows)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aDynamicArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(3);
for(int i=0; i<3, i++)
{
    aDynamicArray.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

then following line will give you access to `x[2][3]`:

```
aDynamicArray.get(2).get(3);
```

Comment: Why is it required to grow it in both the directions? Where did OP mention it?

Comment: OP mentioned in comments: `thanks for the replies. @Affe.. I just want it to grow in 1-D.. the second dimension lenght is fixed.`

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, expected to see that in the question.  However, I then have to comment that using an array of a generic type is not (well) supported in Java.  You're stuck using the raw type, which should never be done in new code.

Comment: Thanks, So the size of the arraylist is just the number of rows i want ? is it the maximum value of i in a[i] [j]?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct but terminiology is not.The first line of code defines an `array` of size `two` that can hold two arraylists.

Comment: sorry about that.. dont you mean array of size 100, that can hold two arraylists?

Comment: Nope, array of size two. i.e. two indexes. and each index holds an `ArrayList` and each `ArrayList` holds as many `int`s required.

Comment: but i want to vary the indexes at run time...by second dimension i meant the 90 in x[100] [90].. hmm.. i ll find a workaround.. a final question, if i wanted to access x[2] [3] , how would i do that in the arraylist?

Comment: x[2][3] means, 3rd row and 4th column. it means in place of creating an array with 2 indexes, you should create with 3. Check the edited answer.

Comment: @Azodious: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was trying to say you *can't* do `new ArrayList<Integer>[3]` as it's a compile error in Java.  You *can* do `new ArrayList[3]` (the raw type) but shouldn't because you shouldn't use raw types in new code.  Therefore this approach, mixing arraylists and arrays, is not a great approach.  An `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

In java would be something like:

```
int [][] x = new int [100] [100]

ArrayList <Integer> y = new ArrayList();

y.add(some number);
```

More information about [Arraylist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Java let you have a collection compose by different data types. For Example

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(1);
list.add("Java");
list.add(3.14);
```

Thus you can also use ArrayList of ArrayList and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of array (you have mentioned as 99), you can use `int[][] intA = new int[100][100]` and If you are familiar in java, you can implement your own Growing `int[][]` by monitoring array size when adding element.

Assume you are adding last element `intA[99][99] = someInt` at this time you can create new array `int[][] newIntA = new int[intA.length+25][100];` then you need to copy content of existing `intA` array to `newIntA`

or you can use `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` to add your values or use `ArrayList[]` its your choice.

Comment: would not using a vector of vector have the same effect?

Comment: ArrayList and Vetor both are implementation of List but ArrayList is preferable than Vector